# Questions that only generate opinions

Tags: discussion

Are we going to continue to let these types of questions float around?
[What to do with grains after mashing?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/388/what-can-i-do-with-my-spent-grain-after-mashing)
Despite many great responses and voting activity its not a question with an answer.  Does the integrity of the stackexchange project suffer I when these questions are allowed to live as long as they do?  While I like these types of questions and answers they don't fit the rigid confines of the SE construct.

Comment: Would it maybe make more sense to turn questions like this into community wikis?

Answer (score 1):

I'm torn on that.   On the one hand, you are correct:  There is no singular "best" answer to the question.   On the other hand, I actually gained some valuable insight into what else I could do with my grain (other than composting) from that question or one like it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I say you need to get that info at another site.  Its the nature of the SE platform.  Not everything fits here.  I like the info gathered from them too, but I am just trying to be a stickler about what SE is about.

Comment: That one in particular also crosses over into the realms of at least 2 other SEs, but both would be demand-side, rather than supply-side (cooking & gardening).   I CW'd it earlier today.

Comment: I agree. the value for SE for me is often when googling, a good SE question appears at the top of the list. I don't care if there isn't a single specific answer - suggestions are often an equally useful. Many heads are better than one, and this site condenses that collective expertise into easily digestible bites.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question. However, I don't think that the "integrity" of SE will suffer. In the case of something like the spent grains questions, why not just turn it into a community wiki and have done with it. The community wiki seems to be something of an "oddbin" for general opinion and for questions which have no definitive answer.